# CMake does not use toolchain file

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, cmake

I am creating an entirely new CMake build with the ARM toolchain.
I ran the following command:

```
cmake -DCMAKETOOLCHAINFILE=../arm-none-eabi-gcc.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug  ../
```

Even though there are no cache files in the build directory, this is the output:

````
cmake -DCMAKETOOLCHAINFILE=../arm-none-eabi-gcc.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug  ../ 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKETOOLCHAINFILE


-- Build files have been written to: /home/alejandro/projects/ST-LIB/build ```
````

Why is CMake not using my toolchain file?

I run the cmake command in the build directory inside my library, so ../ is correct for the relative path.

Comment: try [CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html)

Comment: Worked, thanks! The tutorial is misleading then https://dev.to/younup/cmake-on-stm32-the-beginning-3766

Comment: @AlanBirtles do you mind turning the comment into an answer with some extra info as possible?

Comment: "The tutorial is misleading then" - Why? The tutorial uses variable `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` and doesn't use `CMAKETOOLCHAINFILE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo. It should be [`CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html).